# What is BF3's capability when dealing with lag?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

Because upto 24 players in PS3 (64 players in PC) are scattered around the globe during a match, does BF3 balance gameplay to minimise lag issues by universally setting the ping response time for all connected players in a match ?

For example if you have a range of players in a match with between 25ms to 90 ms ping, will BF3 balance this with a controlled response time to all players of no faster than, say 40ms ? Or something like this to help balance the gameplay ?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt EA would penalize the user for having a good connection.  Most Servers have the option to autokick if the user's ping is too high (normally over 300). This prevents users from warping (lagging) from location to location and possibly benefiting from it (debatable).  This autokick is *that* balance for response time.

Comment: Yeah, and though it is possible to pl

Comment: Yeah and since the player can freely choose where to play it would be really awful to fix the response time on all players. For example: If a european player decides to play on an US server you couldn't just punish them all because he has a ping 300.

Answer (score 0):

BF3 checks for hits locally, on the client, thus you experience no ping whatsoever. (you don't have to aim your shots) Incidentially, this is also the reason that hacking and cheating is running rampant on the PC version of BF3.